# Spring - Lazy Injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am working with version Spring 4.0 and learning DI in Java. I have a `Shape` interface and once class that implements it:

```java
@Component
@Lazy
@Scope(value="prototype")
public class Circle implements Shape {
    public Circle() {
        System.out.println("Ctor Circle");
    }
    @Override
    public double GetArea() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2.0;
    }
}
```

and simple class which will get the shape in injection

```java
@Service
@Lazy
public class ShapeHolder {
    @Autowired
    //@Lazy
    private Shape cShape; 

    public ShapeHolder() {
        System.out.println("Ctor shapeHolder");
    }
}
```

when the `@Lazy` above the field is commented all is working however when it isn't commented, I am getting exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shapeHolder': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.base.Interfaces.Shape com.base.services.ShapeHolder.cShape; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
```

Am I doing something wrong? I want that the injection will be real Lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice`, spring lazy initialization depdens on `aopalliance jar`

If you are using maven, you need to add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```